EC2 Public IPv4 DNS "Unable to Connect
I have pushed a Dockerfile (see below) to the Container Registry (ECR), used a task to deploy said Dockerfile to an ECS Cluster that uses both EC2 and Fargate. Here is the Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.10

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True
WORKDIR $APP_HOME


COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir gunicorn
# Install Python dependencies and Gunicorn


RUN groupadd -r app && useradd -r -g app app



# Copy the rest of the codebase into the image
COPY --chown=app:app . ./
USER app

# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn
# webserver, with one worker process and 8 threads.
# For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers
# to be equal to the cores available in Cloud Run.
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :5000 --log-level info --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 index:server

I have also updated the security group to have the following inbound rules to be completely open to all public traffic:
Network Rules
Yet when I click the public DNS, it still does not load even though the EC2 instance is running and the container is deployed.
this is the error

Unable to connect

An error occurred during a connection to ec2-18-222-141-140.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com.
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the web.

What could the problem be?
I did something similar with Cloud Run and it worked without any issues, though I am trying AWS in hopes of improved speed.
Changed security group inbound/outbound rules, checked gateway and vpc and all was according to what AWS documentation suggested to remedy the problem.

Your container is listening on port 5000. When you "click the IP address" the web browser is going to try connecting to port 80 by default. You may have mapped port 80 in the ECS task definition to port 5000 on the container, but you haven't shown anything in your question to indicate you did that. Also, depending on the ECS network mode you selected, you may have a separate IP address for the ECS task that you need to use, instead of the EC2 server's IP address. Edit your question to include your task definition JSON.

Also you say you are using both EC2 and Fargate, but you don't indicate why you are using both. If you are deploying to Fargate, then of course going to the EC2 instance IP is not going to work. Fargate is more similar to Cloud Run than EC2, but AWS App Runner is even more similar to Cloud Run.
